# How to extract JSONArray to an given array format by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I get some json data form my web server,the data like this:

```
 [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}]
```

how can i get the data like this by using javascript?：

```
 [2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]
```

I have being trying a lot of ways,but still not work!anyone help?

**Question 2nd:**

Here exists an another problem:

- How can i replace the static data in the function bbb() by using the
  result from aaa()??

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function aaa(){
    var a = [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}];
    var b = a.map(function(item){
        return item.zfl;
        })
}
function bbb(){
    mydata:[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]
}
</script>
```

Maybe i can use it like this in bbb() :

```
function bbb(){
     mydata:aaa()
 }
```

- but how to realize it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think your **zfl** is not static all time so I suggest to use
>   Object.keys so that if you don't know key then also it works

```
var a = [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}];

var b = a.map(function(item){
var temp = Object.keys(item)
  return item[temp]
})
console.log(b);
```

**2nd Quetion Answer:**

---

> Use return statement:

```
function aaa(){
        var a = [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}];

        var b = a.map(function(item){
        var temp = Object.keys(item)
          return item[temp]
        })
        return b;
    }

function bbb(){
      mydata = aaa();
      console.log(mydata)
  }
```

Now call bbb() it will print console and if you want to get data from bbb function  to some variable then  then use return statement in bbb() and and call like this:

```
var output = bbb()
```

> For integer output use   **return parseInt(item[temp])**

```js
    function aaa(){
            var a = [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}];
            
            var b = a.map(function(item){
            var temp = Object.keys(item)
               return parseInt(item[temp])
            })
            return b;
        }
    
    function bbb(){
          mydata = aaa();
          console.log(mydata)
      }

  bbb()
```

Comment: If `temp` is an array of object keys, what do you suppose `item[temp]` is?

Comment: if you see above example temp is an array with only one value and if you provide item[["zfl"]] and item["zfl"] in both case it works try to print temp you will see difference

Comment: It works.and It seems that u provide a flexible way to my project.thank u!

Comment: the result will be:
["2.0", "4.9", "7.0", "23.2", "25.6", "76.7", "135.6", "162.2", "32.6", "20.0", "6.4", "3.3"].
but i don't want the double quotation marks,,just like this:
[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]
can u show me how to make it out?

Comment: ya sure use   return parseInt(item[temp])

Comment: If you Want anything  just let me know :D

Comment: @Keval Bhatt You means how to search answers from stackoverflow or ?

Answer (score 1):

Use ***[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)*** to extract the values in a new array.

```
var a = [{"zfl":"2.0"},{"zfl":"4.9"},{"zfl":"7.0"},{"zfl":"23.2"},{"zfl":"25.6"},{"zfl":"76.7"},{"zfl":"135.6"},{"zfl":"162.2"},{"zfl":"32.6"},{"zfl":"20.0"},{"zfl":"6.4"},{"zfl":"3.3"}];

var b = a.map(function(item){
  return item.zfl;
})
console.log(b); //Will contain all your values
```

Comment: It works.thank u!but here still exists a problem,i edit my question again,can u figure it out?

Comment: @hijack. R u trying to assign the new array to `myData`?

Comment: 1.nono,Not to assign the new array to myData.I just need to replace the position beside the "myData:"  by using a function call.
2.On the other hand,ur solution exists a problem:
ur result will be:
["2.0", "4.9", "7.0", "23.2", "25.6", "76.7", "135.6", "162.2", "32.6", "20.0", "6.4", "3.3"]
but i don't want the double quotation marks,just like this:
[2.0, 4.9, 7.0, 23.2, 25.6, 76.7, 135.6, 162.2, 32.6, 20.0, 6.4, 3.3]
How to make it out?

Comment: Finally,I reference u and Keval Bhatt answers to solved my problem.Thanks.:)